# Call error according to request environment like GET or POST

Tags: php, environment

My php script self describe every thing what want to do with this script

**Environment #1**
Request comes through POST by form from previous page action to below script

**Environment #2**
Request comes through GET for my clients to share download link for one use

Now every thing is perfect in below script but I want to call the error according to request environment like if GET request is invalid then error `Your download code is invalid or expires` and if POST request is invalid then error `header ('location: ../Download-token')`
please help

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['dlCODE']) and ($_GET['Rfile'])){
    $reqfname   = $_GET['Rfile'];
    $dlKEY      = trim($_GET['dlCODE']);
    $kfile      = file('Download-Keys.php');
    foreach($kfile as &$one) {
        if(rtrim($one)==$dlKEY) {
            $slink  = true;
            $one    = '';
        }
    }
    file_put_contents('Download-Keys.php', $kfile);
}

if(isset($_POST['Rf'])){
    @session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['download-token'])){
    header("location:../Downloads-Passing");
    }
    $reqfname       = $_POST['Rf'];
    $dlREQ          = true;
}




if(($slink == true) or ($dlREQ == true)){

//Below Variables for Defines value hereinafter use;
$explode        = explode('.',$reqfname);
$t              = time();
$Clintfname     = $explode[0]."_".$t.'.'.$explode[1];
$fPath          = "../qd_files/";


//Below code for force to browser display save as dialogue box options;
header('Content-type: application/zip');

//Below code for rename the source file name to escape hot-linking;
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$Clintfname);

//Below code for Sending correct file size to be ready to Download;
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fPath.$reqfname));

//Below code for read original file from the source;
readfile($fPath.$reqfname);

//Below code for Count Download hit on download button;
$dlfile     =   "dlcounter.php";
$dlcoun     =   file_get_contents($dlfile);
/*PUT ADD ONE*/ file_put_contents($dlfile, ++$dlcoun);

} else {
/*
**
**
**
**
**
        errors need here
**
**
**
**
**
*/
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need define the error inside of each Environment, maybe:

```
<?php
$error = 0;

if(isset($_GET['dlCODE']) and ($_GET['Rfile'])){
    $reqfname   = $_GET['Rfile'];
    $dlKEY      = trim($_GET['dlCODE']);
    $kfile      = file('Download-Keys.php');
    foreach($kfile as &$one) {
        if(rtrim($one)==$dlKEY) {
            $slink  = true;
            $one    = '';
        }else {$error  = 1;}
    }
    file_put_contents('Download-Keys.php', $kfile);
}

if(isset($_POST['Rf'])){
    @session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['download-token'])){$error = 2;}
    $reqfname       = $_POST['Rf'];
    $dlREQ          = true;

}

switch($error)
{
   case 1: echo 'Your download code is invalid or expires'; Break;
   case 2: header ('location: ../Download-token'); Break;
   default:

    //Below Variables for Defines value hereinafter use;
    $explode        = explode('.',$reqfname);
    $t              = time();
    $Clintfname     = $explode[0]."_".$t.'.'.$explode[1];
    $fPath          = "../qd_files/";


    //Below code for force to browser display save as dialogue box options;
    header('Content-type: application/zip');

    //Below code for rename the source file name to escape hot-linking;
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$Clintfname);

    //Below code for Sending correct file size to be ready to Download;
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fPath.$reqfname));

    //Below code for read original file from the source;
    readfile($fPath.$reqfname);

    //Below code for Count Download hit on download button;
    $dlfile     =   "dlcounter.php";
    $dlcoun     =   file_get_contents($dlfile);
    /*PUT ADD ONE*/ file_put_contents($dlfile, ++$dlcoun);

    Break;
}
```